# How much of a disadvantage would it be to pursue admission into a graduate program in education as a math undergrad?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics

As a junior math undergraduate student in Hong Kong, I am currently completing my degree and have a strong desire to pursue further studies in the United States. My ultimate goal is to become a professor or researcher in the faculties of education at a university. I am deeply intrigued by the field of education and have already published several papers on career planning and readiness, as well as conducted research on mathematics education in collaboration with fellow students and professors in my institution's education department. I am concerned about the potential disadvantage of not having taken any education-related courses when applying for graduate schools in the United States.

Comment: It would be a disadvantage. But you have other advantages, like having published papers, which likely outweigh the negatives.  No one is perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the US it is quite common for people to change fields between undergraduate and graduate school. If you are interested in a career in academia focused on math education then an undergrad degree in math with some (even a little) experience in the educational issues will probably be sufficient for admission. Having done collaborative research, even in a minor way, at this point is also a plus.

I'd judge you to be a good candidate, though you need to also be aware that there is a lot of competition. Moreover, it is common to go from an undergraduate degree directly to a doctoral program without needing a masters first. Don't neglect that fact.

Comment: I randomly checked two programs in my state and both required  a master's degree but those might be more focused on K-12 education and people who are already working in the field.

Comment: @mkennedy, yes, there aren't very many universals in the US education system. But requiring a masters to begin a doctorate is much more common in Europe and maybe elsewhere.